# How to store and retrieve audio files from a database into VB 2008?

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to find a way to store a `.wav file` in a database (Access) and then retrieve it into Visual Basic 2008 application.

I can do it for an image file, but whatever I've tried for audio files has been a failure so far. I have done a lot of searching in different sites, but it seems that no one has had this need since I haven't found a single site that addresses this.

By the way, I don't want to store a pointer to the file on disk by storing the file directory information. I want the actual contents of the file to be stored in the database, the same way that I am doing with the graphics file. Is it possible to do it? How?

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: what is your database ?

Comment: I am using MS Access, but I could switch to MySql if need be.

Comment: *How* does it fail?  Does it fail to create a record in the DB, or it *does* create a record, but the column where the data should be is zero, or null, or... ?

Comment: Could you post your code to read/write to db

Comment: I imagine you'll have to use a binary field in the database, and then write the contents of the .wav file to the binary field via some sort of stream.  Try googling for how to save binary data in Access.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the .wav in a local file;

```
Dim filestring as string = application.startuppath & "\filename.wav"
```

Use the database to hold the filename, then MCI strings etc. to play it from wherever you stored it before.

However if you're quite sure you want to find it from the directory, I'd send the problem in to daniweb, see if they know.